# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command + VS Code + Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx

I am getting the error "'npm' is not recognised as an internal or external command" while creating project in VS code using Salesforce CLI. Don't know what I am missing out. Can anyone guide me.

[image]

Comment: NPM is part of Node.Js, you have to install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) for it. Node is not installed along with Salesforce CLI installation.

Comment: Than you Raul. But could you please let me know why the need to install Node.js as I need to work with Salesforce Apex

Comment: You just mentioned the `npm` problem, but maybe you should edit your question and add proper details on what is the exact issue.

Comment: I have just added the error message that I am getting when I try to create a new project in VS

Comment: I see you are trying to create a project, sfdx uses `node.js` under the hood for its tooling and it is a prerequisite. Please try installing nde and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started facing the same issue, the very moment I updated Salesforce CLI to the latest version "*sfdx-cli/7.56.1-2773b53bf5*".

Everything was fine before this version of CLI, however, seems that this version requires NPM package manager as well for CLI to run but it's not auto-installed or prompted by any means during CLI update that it's required.

The only solution I found to make it work as of now on **my Windows machine**, is by installing the **NPM package manager** and it started to work like it was.

Comment: Alternatively, installing nodejs would suffice.

Comment: Installing NodeJs did the trick. Thank you all for the guidance.

Comment: Thanks! it worked

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing this error..... is because of the Node.js not installed or it has older version.
I have installed latest node.js with npm from https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

this solved the issue!

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to install. Google failed me when I searched for it

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the Node.js not installed or it has older version install latest node.js with npm from https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

Setup user variable for the installed Node.js --> "C:\Program Files\nodejs

Which will solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Installing node.js fixed the "npm not recognized as...." error, which I started getting abruptly today (was working fine till yesterday).  Also, I only saw this error while creating components. Other commands (e.g. sfdx deploy ) worked fine even before the node.js install.