# Not able to create a project in vs code?SFDX: Create Project failed to run

Tags: vs-code

This is the following error i am getting....

Starting SFDX: Create Project

```
11:39:05.943 sfdx force:project:create --projectname gfgfgf --outputdir c:\Users\SAMEER\Desktop\ToDoManager --template standard
ERROR running force:project:create:  Command failed with exit code 1: npm root -g --prefix c:\Users\SAMEER\Desktop\ToDoManager\.yo-repository --loglevel error
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
11:39:07.122 sfdx force:project:create --projectname gfgfgf --outputdir c:\Users\SAMEER\Desktop\ToDoManager --template standard
 ended with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you try installing Node Package Manager CLI? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per ['npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command + VS Code + Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304554/npm-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-vs-code-salesforc) this appears to be an issue many users reported after having Salesforce CLI updated to the latest version "sfdx-cli/7.56.1-2773b53bf5"

So the solution would be to either install the NPM package manager or install nodejs.

Comment: Npm package manager ,where can I find this ??.is it in vs code extension ?